# how to give diffrent tasks to diffrent people?

Tags: python, task, cpu-word

so i have a school project to make a python program that gives people diffrent tasks. i'm pretty new at python so i made a code like this:

```
from random import *
tasks = [input("task: " ), input("task: " ), input("task: " ), input("task: " ), input("task: " ), 
input("task: " ) ]
person1 = [input("name: ")]
person2 = [input("name: ")]
person3 = [input("name: ")]
person4 = [input("name: ")]

shuffle(tasks)
first = str(person1) + str(choice(tasks))
second = str(person2) + str(choice(tasks))
third = str(person3) + str(choice(tasks))
fourth = str(person4) + str(choice(tasks))

print (first)
print (second)
print (third)
print (fourth)
```

but sometimes it gives the same task for two or more people. How can i make it that it would give diffrent tasks to everyone?

Comment: You've already `shuffle`d your list. Why are you then using `random.choice`? Just take the first item, then the second, then the third, then the fourth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `tasks` is already shuffled at that point, using `choice(tasks)` is incorrect. Just do `first = tasks[0]`, `second = tasks[1]` etc.